# Use active record to find a record by month and day, ignoring year and time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a model (Entries) with five years worth of records (one record per day). I need a method that, when passed a date object such as `2011-12-25 00:00:00`, will show me ALL the records that have happened on 12/25 (querying against the `:created_at` column), regardless of the year or time that's passed.

RoR 3.0.9 / Ruby 1.9.2p290

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the MONTH and DAY values of mysql.  Maybe something like:

```
Model.where("MONTH(created_at) = ? and DAY(created_at) = ?", somedate.month, somedate.day)
```

Comment: You could also maybe use DATE_FORMAT. Not sure which would be faster though. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: You could use EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM last_request_at) as well. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract

Answer (score 12):

A general solution that should work with most SQL databases (include MySQL and PostgreSQL):

```
Entry.where('extract(month from created_at) = ? AND extract(day from created_at) = ?', d.month, d.day)
```

SQLite doesn't understand `extract` though so you'd have to use:

```
Entry.where("strftime('%m/%d', created_at) = ?", d.strftime('%m/%d'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are using mysql:

```
User.where(["DAY(created_at) = ? AND MONTH(created_at) = ?", date.day, date.month])
```

Answer (score 2):

Assume RDBMS is MySQL and you have form with combobox to select month and/or date_of_months, may be you could make a named_scope, for example :

```
scope :by_date_or_month, lambda { |date, month| {:conditions => ["DAYOFMONTH(created_at) = ? or MONTH(created_at) = ?", date, month]}}
```

Test from IRB :

```
Model.by_date_or_month(31,8)
Model.by_date_or_month(nil,8)
```