# SQLite: group records by month they were created and get a count of records per month

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, querying

I know, I know there's a couple very similar questions to this, but they handle Postgres and MySQL.

I have a model (Event) that tracks page visits, I want to group then count events created per month, and show this using Chart.js. But I don't get how to query SQLite to collect events created at a certain month.

SQLite can't handle `EXTRACT()`, or something like this `Model.where("MONTH(created_at) = ?", 9)`.

I also tried this `Event.where("strftime('%-m', created_at) = ?", 9)` suggested by this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102020/use-active-record-to-find-a-record-by-month-and-day-ignoring-year-and-time), with no luck. It just returns `0` no matter what month I try.

As a hack-y long shot, I even tried adding a `month` column to Event, filling that with `created_at.month`, but later gave up on that branch.

I'm very new to Rails development and am shaky on querying, but I've looked at the following questions and still can't piece anything together: 
[How to make a query in Postgres to group records by month they were created? (:created_at datetime column)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757803/how-to-make-a-query-in-postgres-to-group-records-by-month-they-were-created-c), [Selecting by month in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8863156/selecting-by-month-in-postgresql), [Getting count of elements by `created_at` by day in a given month](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2043388/getting-count-of-elements-by-created-at-by-day-in-a-given-month), [Group records by both month and year in Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12526161/group-records-by-both-month-and-year-in-rails), [Use active record to find a record by month and day, ignoring year and time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7102020/use-active-record-to-find-a-record-by-month-and-day-ignoring-year-and-time)

Comment: Why %-m instead of %m ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650480/get-month-from-datetime-in-sqlite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Bloc.io mentor led me to this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/29-group-by-month

So I can do something like this to return a hash with months as the keys:

`months = Event.all.group_by { |t| t.created_at.beginning_of_month }`

Answer (score 0):

The correct substitution for `strftime` is `%m`, not `%-m`.

Furthermore, `strftime` returns a zero-padded string:

```
.where("strftime('%m', created_at) = ?", "09")
```

Comment: Yeah that's why I did `%-m` so that it wouldn't be zero-padded. Even with just `%m` I get the same output.